# iOS 9 ShareData between AppGroup through NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift2, ios-extensions, ios-app-group

I'm trying to add TodayExtension to my existing app and I want that app and extension will share data through NSUserDefaults.
According to this tutorial http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/
I did like it say:

- Create new target with Today extension
- Add new App-Group in Extension and App
- Add code to app
- Add code to extension

**App Code**

```
func updateExtensionData() {
    let key = "identityCode"
    let valueForStore:Float = 2.0
    let extensiontDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.company.mineSharedDefaults")
    extensiontDefaults?.setFloat(valueForStore, forKey: key)
    let results = extensiontDefaults?.synchronize()
    let checkCode = extensiontDefaults?.objectForKey(key)
    print("code for save \(valueForStore) synchronize result \(results) readed code \(checkCode!)")
}
```

**Extension code**

```
private func updateData() {
    let key = "identityCode"
    let extensionDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.company.mineSharedDefaults")
    let checkCode = extensionDefaults?.floatForKey(key)
    print("synchronize result \(resut) readed code \(checkCode!)")
}
```

**Issue**

My issue is that extension always read 0 instead of 2. Clearly I'm missing something. There is some major difference between iOS8 and 9 in case of AppGroup and NSUserDefaults? I know that there is but between app an watchOS2.

For being more clear this is keys from App and Extension NSUserDefaults

**App Keys**

> AppleKeyboards
>
> AppleKeyboardsExpanded
>
> AddingEmojiKeybordHandled
>
> AppleLanguages
>
> ApplePasscodeKeyboards
>
> PreferredLanguages
>
> AppleLocale
>
> NSInterfaceStyle
>
> MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey
>
> NSLanguages
>
> AppleITunesStoreItemKinds
>
> identityCode
>
> AppleLanguagesDidMigrate
>
> PKEnableStockholmSettings

**Extension Keys**

> AppleKeyboards
>
> AppleKeyboardsExpanded
>
> AddingEmojiKeybordHandled
>
> AppleLanguages
>
> ApplePasscodeKeyboards
>
> PreferredLanguages
>
> AppleLocale
>
> NSInterfaceStyle
>
> MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey
>
> NSLanguages
>
> AppleITunesStoreItemKinds
>
> AppleLanguagesDidMigrate
>
> PKEnableStockholmSettings

It's clear that key `identityCode` is not appearing in extension at all.

Comment: have you tried to store/retrieve a NSNumber instead of a float? I see that in the first code you store using setFloat but you retrieve it using objectForKey. If it is stored as fload you should use floatForKey

Comment: I try with String stored as object and extension read it as nil. I've also checked keys and there is no key with name `identityCode`.

Comment: can you explain why checkCode is using objectForKey in the first code and floatForKey on the second?

Comment: Well I guess it's mine mistake, rest when I experiment with String, but this change nothing.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: What's the point creating another key if any of those are accessible  between app and extension. Nither I try with `thiIsMySuperUniqueKey`. Same result.

Comment: these keys are internally used by iOS. You cannot use them to store your stuff.

Comment: Where I say that I'm using those listed keys? I've just print them to show that when I do it then in app side there is one more key (this is key which I add) and on extension key there is not.

Comment: you are using it here: `let key = "identityCode"`. You define that and then store the values using it. You cannot do that. This key is reserved by iOS. You must create your own key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure what helps but I've done two thing:

- rename current AppGroup identifier and create new one with name `group.my.entire.bundle.id.of.my.app.sharedData` instead of `group.appname.sharedData`
- remove and create new AppGroup identifier

I can use "identityCode" as key.

Answer (score 0):

CThere could be several things!
first; did you allow keychain sharing under "Capabilities" for both your container app and the extension, and did you set the Keychain groups to the same group?

I recommend using this: https://github.com/kefbytes/KeychainWrapper
download it, it's very simple, just add the swiftfile to your project

allow keychain sharing under cabailities, 
set your serviceName and accesgroup like this

> KeychainWrapper.serviceName = "give it a name in here"

(servicename is neccessary for it to work)

> KeychainWrapper.accessGroup = "write your accessgroup name here"

(accesgroup is optional, since you are setting it under Capabilities)

save a value to a key like this

> KeychainWrapper.setString("2", forKey: "identityCode"

and retrieve with

> KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("identityCode")